# Angular2 directives modifying its html host

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm using Angular 2 and I would like a directive to modify the behaviour of its host html element. For example, I would like an `InnerDirective` with selector `'[inner-directive]'` such that:

```html
@Component({
selector: '[outer-component]'
template: `
<div
  inner-directive
></div>
`
})
class outerComponent{
someAttribute: boolean;
}
```

is the same as

```html
@Component({
selector: '[outer-component]'
template: `
<div
  [ngClass] = "{'some-class': someAttribute}"
></div>
`
})
class outerComponent{
someAttribute: boolean;
}
```

I don't want `InnerDirective` to be a component with its own template doing the job (with `someAttribute` getting passed down) because that would create a redundant html element.

More generally I would like to do whatever can be achieved by putting an empty component inside another component (with the aforementioned html redundancy), by getting the inner component to be a directive instead. That way my "leaves" can all be directives.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[innerDirective]',
  host: {'[class.some-class]': 'innerDirective'}
})
class InnerDirective {
  @Input() innerDirective: boolean;
}
```

- `host: {'[class.some-class]': 'someAttribute'}` binds the value of the `innerDirective` input to `some-class` on the host element.
- An input with the same name as the selector (`@Input() innerDirective: boolean;`) allows terse binding syntax (shown below)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: '[outer-component]',
  directives: [InnerDirective],
  template: `
<div [innerDirective]="someAttribute"></div>`
})
class outerComponent{
  someAttribute: boolean;
}
```

- `[innerDirective]="someAttribute"` binds the `someAttribute` value to the `innerDirective` input of `InnerDirective`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just a quick follow-up: what do you mean by terse binding syntax? Why is it `host: {'[class.some-class]': 'someAttribute'} })` and not `host: {'[class.some-class]': 'innerDirective'} })` ? Can this work if I need more than one input?

Comment: What I mean with "terse" is that you can use `[innerDirective]="someAttribute"` instead of `inner-directive [someAttribute]="someAttribute"`. Thanks for the hint, I fixed the name (`someAttribute` -> `innerDirective`)

Answer (score 1):

It's typically what attribute directive aims to. It allows to change the appearance or behavior of the element it applies on.

Here is a sample:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[inner-directive]'
})
export class InnerDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

**Update**

You can leverage the `host` attribute when defining your directive

```
@Directive({
  (...)
  host: {
    '[class.myClass]': 'displayClass',
    '[attr.someAttr]': 'someAttrValue',
    '[attr.otherAttr]': 'someValue'
  }
})
export class InnerDirective {
  @Input('innner-directive')
  someValue: string;

  constructor() {
    // myClass is added on the host
    this.displayClass = true;

    // myClass isn't added on the host
    // this.displayClass = false;

    this.someAttrValue = 'some value';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.someValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can this really be adapted to bind a property of a dom element (e.g. the class, background color etc) to the value of some expression? Doesn't the constructor just get executed once?

Comment: Yes you can bind attributes / classes using the `host` configuration property.  Things are in this case dynamic. I updated my answer accordingly...